# Additional Join Slows Performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the sql statement below that runs in 5 minutes max.  When I add any joins to it, the sql statement runs until it times out.  I was wondering if you could let me know why adding to the sql statement causes this?  These are the joins that I have added to the base SQL:

***Added this statement to Base SQL***

```
inner join ahsrelate.dbo.ahs_encounter ahs_encounter_1
on AHS_Encounter_1.PatientID=AHS_Patient.ID
```

***Or Added this Statement to Base SQL***

```
inner join AHS_Medication
on ahs_medication.patientid=AHS_Patient.ID
```

***Base SQL***

```
SELECT distinct
    AHS_Patient.FullName, 
    AHS_Patient_Iorg.OrganizationMrn, 
    AHS_Patient.SexName, 
    AHS_Patient.DateOfBirth, 
    Finding1.NumericResult, 
    Finding2.NumericResult, 
    AHS_Problem.ICD9DiagnosisCode, 
    AHS_Encounter.EncounterDTTM, 
    AHS_Encounter.EncounterTypeName, 
    AHS_Result.EntryCode, 
    AHS_Result_1.EntryCode, 
    AHS_Result.NumericResult, 
    AHS_Result_1.NumericResult, 
    AHS_Result.ClinicalDTTM, 
    AHS_Result_1.ClinicalDTTM, 
    AHS_Provider.FullName, 
    AHS_Problem.Problem, 
    AHS_Problem.ProblemStatusName, 
    AHS_Encounter.ApptLocationName, 
    AHS_Encounter.AppointmentStatusName
FROM AHSRelate.dbo.AHS_Patient AHS_Patient 
      INNER JOIN AHSRelate.dbo.Finding1 Finding1 
        ON AHS_Patient.ID=Finding1.PatientID
          AND Finding1.EntryMnemonic='BP SYS'    
      INNER JOIN AHSRelate.dbo.Finding2 Finding2 
        ON AHS_Patient.ID=Finding2.PatientID 
        AND Finding2.EntryMnemonic='BP DIAS' 
      INNER JOIN AHSRelate.dbo.AHS_Result AHS_Result 
        ON AHS_Patient.ID=AHS_Result.PatientID
         AND AHS_Result.EntryCode IN ('D5353078', 'Q25015900') 
      INNER JOIN AHSRelate.dbo.AHS_Result AHS_Result_1 
        ON AHS_Patient.ID=AHS_Result_1.PatientID
          AND AHS_Result_1.EntryCode IN ('D5353037', 'Q25003000')
      INNER JOIN AHSRelate.dbo.AHS_Encounter AHS_Encounter 
        ON AHS_Encounter.PatientID=AHS_Patient.ID
        AND AHS_Encounter.AppointmentStatusName='Pending' 
          AND AHS_Encounter.EncounterTypeName='Appointment'
          and AHS_Encounter.EncounterDTTM >= getdate()-1
          and AHS_Encounter.EncounterDTTM <= getdate()+1            
      INNER JOIN AHSRelate.dbo.AHS_Problem AHS_Problem 
        ON AHS_Patient.ID=AHS_Problem.PatientID
      INNER JOIN AHSRelate.dbo.AHS_Patient_Iorg AHS_Patient_Iorg 
        ON AHS_Patient.ID=AHS_Patient_Iorg.PersonID
      inner JOIN AHSRelate.dbo.AHS_Provider AHS_Provider 
        ON AHS_Encounter.Provider2ID=AHS_Provider.ID
    ORDER BY 
    AHS_Patient.FullName, 
    AHS_Result.ClinicalDTTM DESC, 
    AHS_Result_1.ClinicalDTTM DESC
```

Comment: What DBMS are you using? Can you attach an explain plan? Do you have indexes on the columns you are joining on?

Comment: What you are talking about is called performance tuning.  Regardless of what DBMS you are using this is a massive subject that cannot easily be addressed in the context of an answer to a stackoverflow question.  Your best bet would be to post the explain or execution plan in an attempt to have us identify what the problem areas are in your query.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL.  I have indexes on all of the joins.  I was unable to create an explain plan.

Comment: If it's SQL Server it will be called an execution plan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing without knowing the details of your data structure, but am making an educated guess based on my own previous work with health care databases.  I look at this and then look at your query:

```
inner join AHS_Medication
on ahs_medication.patientid=AHS_Patient.ID
```

The first thing that comes to mind is that you have a Patient, who might have multiple problems, and multiple encounters, and multiple medications, and the result is that you are joining things together that aren't related and thus producing far more records than makes sense.  5 minutes is already a long time for a query, and I would bet the medications table is pretty huge comparatively, and thus you are going to multiply the runtime significantly.

Consider your patients:

```
Patient1
Patient2
Patient3
```

Joined with encounters(assuming each patient has two encounters):

```
Patient1  Encounter1
Patient1  Encounter2
Patient2  Encounter3
Patient2  Encounter4
Patient3  Encounter5
Patient3  Encounter6
```

This is fine, but then you join with medications, which is either not in the same hierarchy or you left out join criteria that relates the medication to the Encounter in which it was prescribed(medication.PatientId && medication.EncounterWhichPrescibed).  If Patient1 has three medications, it will get duplicated for each encounter, because there is no relationship between Encounter and Medication(or at least you didn't use it in the join criteria).

```
Patient1  Encounter1  MedicationA
Patient1  Encounter1  MedicationB
Patient1  Encounter1  MedicationC
Patient1  Encounter2  MedicationA
Patient1  Encounter2  MedicationB
Patient1  Encounter2  MedicationC
Patient2  Encounter3  MedicationD
Patient2  Encounter3  MedicationE
Patient2  Encounter3  MedicationF
Patient2  Encounter4  MedicationD
Patient2  Encounter4  MedicationE
Patient2  Encounter4  MedicationF
Patient3  Encounter5  MedicationG
Patient3  Encounter5  MedicationH
Patient3  Encounter5  MedicationI
Patient3  Encounter6  MedicationG
Patient3  Encounter6  MedicationH
Patient3  Encounter6  MedicationI
```

This kind of problem could be occurring for other joins as well and thus each non-sensical join is increasing the runtime geometrically(i.e. 5 minutes could to into 50 minutes easily with a single join).